# VBA in Excel - text box

Tags: vba, input, box

I am working on a spreadsheet and added a button w/ VBA to filter by status of line items in rows.  There are 3 different status types available.  I have it that the user selects the button and gets a input box to enter one of the statuses (with * = ALL status).  The status entered in the input box is inserted in a field to show which filter is selected.  My question is (maybe this is a 2-parter):  If the user select * (for all), how can I get the text "ALL" inserted into the field?  Or, instead of a input box, is there VBA could for a pull down/ option selection of all 3 status options plus "ALL"?  Code used is below.  Thank you! Kathleen

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="1234"
Dim strInput As String
strInput = InputBox("Please enter the status to Filter - enter * for ALL rows")
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("A7:S1006").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=strInput
Range("F3").Value = strInput
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="1234"
```

End Sub

Comment: Without using VBA, you can use Data Validation on a single cell to restrict the user's inputs to the status types - this way you can guarantee the spelling and filtering works the way it should. There is a listbox control that you could use.

Comment: Thank you.  I have data validation for the data input but there are multiple filters required and want to use macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Replace` function

```vba
strInput = Replace(InputBox("Please enter the status to Filter - enter * for ALL rows"), "*", "ALL")
```

Comment: @Kat Glad I could help you. Please mark this as the answer, so that the question shows as closed for other SO users.